# SQL Total time based on Timestamp and States

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Timestamp            | State
01-jan-2016 00:01:00 | ON
01-jan-2016 00:02:00 | OFF
01-jan-2016 00:02:01 | ON
01-jan-2016 00:03:00 | OFF
```

A Sample result would look like, considering `NOW` is 01-Jan-2016 `00:03:10`.

```
State | TotalTime
ON    |  00:01:59
OFF   |  00:00:11
```

I'd like to have a query that returns the total time [in hours, mins and secs] for each of the states. Is that possible using SQL Server Express 2012? Any ideas/directions I should take?

Comment: Please post the expected result based on your sample data.

Comment: @PM77-1, Thanks for asking, I just added it.

Comment: Off would be 1 second not 11

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks for the question,  I'm considering NOW as 01-Jan-2016 00:03:10, so state is still OFF.

Comment: Updated answer to include a DEFAULT Date of Jan 1 2016, 3:10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change would be required if you want to see over 24 hours

```
Declare @YourTable table (Timestamp datetime,State varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('01-jan-2016 00:01:00','ON'),
('01-jan-2016 00:02:00','OFF'),
('01-jan-2016 00:02:01','ON'),
('01-jan-2016 00:03:00','OFF')

Declare @Default DateTime ='01-Jan-2016 00:03:10'

;with cteBase as (
    Select *,NextTime = Lead(TimeStamp,1,@Default) over (Order By TimeStamp)
     From @YourTable
)
Select State
      ,Duration=cast(DateAdd(SECOND,sum(DateDiff(SECOND,TimeStamp,NextTime)),cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime)) as time)
 From  cteBase
 Group By State
```

Returns

```
State   Duration
OFF     00:00:11
ON      00:01:59
```

Just a quick note.

`Lead(TimeStamp,1,TimeStamp)` could be `Lead(TimeStamp,1,GetDate())` if you want final state to current.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: @D.Caan Happy to help.  Get comfortable with with the window functions.  They are invaluable.  cheers